# How to using onChildAdded in useEffect react native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm doing a simple app chat with react native and firebase realtime database. I listening database change equal function onChildAdded(). It not work when I put the function inside useEffect(), but when I put it outside useEffect was it work. How to put onChildAdded inside useEffect but still work.
Thank you so much!

[function inside useEffect()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyWIq.png)

[function outside useEffect()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrWNP.png)

[firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNOvd.png)

my code here
function inside useEffect()

it return value the first time render

```
useEffect(() => {
getMessages(ROOM_ID, (messages) => {
  setData(messages);
});
const refToRoom = ref(getDatabase(app), `messages/room_${ROOM_ID}`);
const myQuery = query(refToRoom);
onChildAdded(
  myQuery,
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
return offMessagesChange(ROOM_ID);}, []);
```

when function outside useEffect it return value when data added

```
  useEffect(() => {
getMessages(ROOM_ID, (messages) => {
  setData(messages);
});
return offMessagesChange(ROOM_ID);}, []);
  const refToRoom = ref(getDatabase(app), `messages/room_${ROOM_ID}`);
  const myQuery = query(refToRoom);
 onChildAdded(
myQuery,
(data) => {
  console.log(data);
},
(error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be helpful

```
useEffect(() => {
getMessages(ROOM_ID, (messages) => {
  setData(messages);
});
const refToRoom = ref(getDatabase(app), `messages/room_${ROOM_ID}`);
const myQuery = query(refToRoom);

// wrap your function inside setTimeout
 setTimeout(() => {

  onChildAdded(
  myQuery,(data) => {
    console.log(data);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
return offMessagesChange(ROOM_ID);
  }, 1000) //add this ,1000 mean 1 second delay.
}, []);
```

Comment: thank you for supporting, but its not working in my case

Comment: you said function not working mean function calling start and further not responding or function calling not start?

Comment: In the first time it work, but next time when I add new data in firebase database it not get reponse